# How do you report a moderator who has consistently showed a trend to be obviously biased?

Tags: discussion

I have observed a moderator on this site who consistently removes people's questions and answers and flags posts because they do not reinforce his/her ideology. I have noticed this trend against multiple users including myself. I recently posted an answer to a question that was backed up by 3 highly credible sources including a Congressional report and an interview by the lead investigator of that Congressional investigation and quotes from a 100 year old publication. As well as quotes from historical world leaders.

My question is:

is there any recourse for this bias?

Comment: Alternative explanation: you are pushing your own ideology at many places where it's completely inappropriate.

Comment: @ Martin Tournoij I would totally accept that if it were only my posts and they weren't completely backed up with sources, but I have seen the trend with many other people's posts as well.

Comment: The emotional adjectives I see here are less useful than a concrete description of one such incident would be. That is: toning down the accusations (like "tyrannical") and adding excerpts might help (if that's your route; also suggested in the answer below). Without, the public present here cannot help. –– But: Meta *is the place* to discuss these matters. Therefore I do not see why 3 downvotes are necessary to pile on this post (while improvements to it are welcome). (at)Aporter please increase the "usefulness" of this post with an [edit]. @Downvoters: if edited, revisit & reconsider, pls.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges

Comment: Do you have a link to the question/answer you are referring to?

Answer (score 10):

If you would like to discuss a moderators decision in public, create a question on [Politics Meta](https://meta.politics.stackexchange.com) where you:

1. link to the question/answer where you believe a moderator made a wrong decision (users with a high enough reputation can read deleted questions and answers)
2. explain why you think the decision was wrong in this particular case

Note that your request has a higher chance to be received in a positive light when you try to remain factual, assume good faith and refrain from insults. We all want to make Politics Stack Exchange the best site it can be, but we might not always agree on what that means. A polite and respectful discourse is the best way to come to a consensus in this matter.

---

If you would prefer your appeal to be handled by the [community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do) in private, you can contact them via the [contact form](https://politics.stackexchange.com/contact) linked from the footer of the site. The community team manages the moderators on beta sites and has the power to appoint and remove them.

Comment: @Magisch Good point. Added.

Comment: As this was migrated from main: was the negative score migrated as well or did the Q start with 0/0 here on meta?

Comment: @LangLangC I saw it first here on meta and I *think* it had -1 at that point, but I am not 100% sure. But that should be a comment on the question, not this answer.